# How do I prevent Laravel from logging 404 errors?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, error-logging

My production laravel log is getting stuffed with 404 errors from bots and the like. I want to be able to review my log daily for real errors, but it's impossible to sort through all of this.

What I would prefer is to log everything *except* 404 errors. Everything else I want to see. What is the best practice for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `App::missing()` function to catch the error and display a 404 page

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors